# MVC4 jQuery AJAX postback never hits controller action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some jQuery scripting that is using AJAX to post back to a controller but the controller is never hit.  There is some sort of error from my AJAX call but it goes by too quickly and I can't read it.

My AJAX:

```
function ValidateByBASFID(basfID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX/ValidateByBASFID',
        data: '{"BASFID":"' + basfID + '"}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result)
                return true;
            else {
                $("#txtBASFIDError").html("Invalid BASF ID");
                return false;
            };
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("An error occured. \nStatus: " + result.status
                            + "\nStatus Text: " + result.statusText
                            + "\nError Result: " + result);
        }
    });
};
```

My Controller:

```
namespace Section_Signup.Controllers
{
    public class AJAXController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ValidateByBASFID(string BASFID)
        {
            Models.Repositories.SectionRepository _repository = new Models.Repositories.SectionRepository();
            MemberVM Member = _repository.GetMemberByBASFID(BASFID);

            if (Member != null)
                return Json(true);
            else
                return Json(false);
        }
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint just inside the controller action, it's never hit.

Comment: Just `data: { BASFID: basfID },`

Comment: Thanks Stephen but I've tested with my AJAX call sending back no data at all (to a dummy controller action I setup for the test) and still the controller action never gets hit.

Comment: And what errors do you get in the browser console? (you should be using `url: '@Url.Action("ValidateByBASFID", "AJAX")',` so the url is correctly, and it also needs to be as per my first comment unless you also set the `contentType: 'json'` option)

Comment: There is no record of the callback being made in the browser console.  There is one odd message there - "uncaught exception: out of memory".  I managed to see what the error the AJAX call was displaying but it only says "[object Object]" with a status of 0.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in how I'm calling the AJAX callback.  I'll figure it out and report the answer.  Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with the asynchronous nature of AJAX.  I was connecting my AJAX callback to a submit button and trying to validate an ID.  If it was invalid, I'd return false to "cancel" the submit.

The thing is that the script wouldn't wait around for the answer to come back and would submit the form directly after making the AJAX call.  If it subsequently came back false, it was too late and it would throw the weird errors.

I've changed my AJAX to read like this:

```
function ValidateByBASFID(basfID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX/ValidateByBASFID',
        data: { BASFID: basfID },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result)
                $('form#formBASFID').submit();
            else {
                $("#txtBASFIDError").html("Invalid BASF ID");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("An error occured. \nStatus: " + result.status
                            + "\nStatus Text: " + result.statusText
                            + "\nError Result: " + result);
        }
    });
};
```

The function that calls this AJAX callback returns false to the submit every time to cancel the submit.  It looks like this:

```
$("#btnBASFID").click(function () {
    var basfID = $("#txtBASFID").val();
    ValidateByBASFID(basfID);
    return false;
});
```

If subsequently this AJAX returns that the ID was valid, a submit is processed again.